# angular http request call multitimes

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have following code in `onInit`:

```
const urlParams = Observable.combineLatest(
  this.route.params,
  this.route.queryParams,
  (params, queryParams) => ({ ...params, ...queryParams })
);

this.id$ = urlParams.map(param => {
  return param.id;
});


this.ofert$ = this.id$.pipe(
  filter(id => !!id),
  switchMap((ofertId: number) => {
    return this.offerService.getWorkOffer(ofertId);
  })
);
```

Why the `this.offerService.getWorkOffer` in   `switchMap` has called 
multitimes?

Comment: `this.id$ = urlParams.map....` <= so `this.id$` is a collection/array the same size as  `urlParams`. So the `pipe` call will iterate over each member. If you used the debugger and stepped through your code you would see that.

Comment: how I can handle with it?

Answer (score 1):

`this.id$ = urlParams.map....` <= `this.id$` is a collection/array the same size as  `urlParams`. The `pipe` call will iterate over each member and, in turn, call `switchMap` which then calls `this.offerService.getWorkOffer` in each iteration.